# How can seed data for a field that be calculated by 2 other field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class of Post entity like this:

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ViewCount { get; set; }
        public int RateCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalRate { get; set; }

        private decimal rate;

        public decimal Rate
        {
            get { return rate; }
            set
            {
                value = (decimal)TotalRate / RateCount;
                rate = value;
            }
        }
     }
```

The value of Rate will be calculated by TotalRate and RateCount. When I seed the data for a Post and save it to my database, I want the Rate value will be automatically calculated and saved into my database. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude computation from your entity, for this purpose, you can change your entity model:

```
 public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ViewCount { get; set; }
    public int RateCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalRate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; }

}
```

And use a model builder in `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext` as follows:

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(p => p.Rate)
            // here is the computed query definition
            .HasComputedColumnSql("[TotalRate]/[RateCount]").HasColumnType("decimal");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: I have just found that, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

your set-accessor is pretty pointless. In particular it doesn't use the *provided* `value` but just overwrites it with *another* `value`. So when doing `myPost.Rate = 3` the value `3` is effectivly ignored.

So in fact you don't need a setter at all, as it makes no sense for a client to assign any value to the property. Just make your *getter* return the computed value appropriately:

```
public decimal Rate
{
    get { return (decimal)TotalRate / RateCount; }
}
```

or a bit shorter:

```
public decimal Rate => (decimal)TotalRate / RateCount;
```